jwt_token decode doesnt work if verify is True
I have created a JWT token in php after logon. After logging in, I am redirected to success.php where there is a link to a bob.php (flask route). Clicking on it says invalid token.
This is my code:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import jwt

app = Flask(__name__)
secret_key = "portal_key"

@app.route('/hi')
def hi():
    token = request.cookies.get('access_token')
    print(f"Token received: {token}")

    if not token:
        return jsonify({"error": "Unauthorized access"}), 401
    
    try:
        
        data = jwt.decode(token, algorithms='HS256', verify=True, key=secret_key)
        print(f"Decoded data: {data}")
        
        username = data['data']['username']
        print(username)

        if not username:
            return jsonify({"error": "Username not found in token"}), 400
        return jsonify({"message": f"Hello, {username}!"})
    
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        return jsonify({"error": "Token expired"}), 401
    except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
        return jsonify({"error": "Invalid token"}), 401
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

The result of data (access_token) is eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJhdWQiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJpYXQiOjE3MzA4MDE5OTAsImV4cCI6MTczMDgwNTU5MCwiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMjQiLCJyb2xlIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNoYW5qaW5nIn19.9q4IZMuZ1SlsOqdMmoJ8XW1mynLclbRn_FfHMP4110U
and the decoded data is
"iss": "localhost",
  "aud": "localhost",
  "iat": 1730801990,
  "exp": 1730805590,
  "data": {
    "user_id": "24",
    "role": "Admin",
    "username": "bob"

If I changed data = jwt.decode(token, algorithms='HS256', verify=True, key=secret_key) to data = jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False}) then it works. But its not secure. I cant find a way to fix the Invalid token error. I have no idea whats causing it, it might be a formatting error?
Thanks in advance.

So what is the actual question? Your title says "doesnt work if verify is False",  but in the body you write "...options={"verify_signature": False}) then it works.", which seems to contradict the title. But the real question seems to be why you have a "Invalid token error.". I suggest to edit your question to clarify the question and give more details about the real problem. If the token is invalid, there should be details in the exception that tell you more about it.

@jps oops, i meant to say that verify is True doesnt work. will update it

Now you at least removed the contradiction, but did not really do anything to clarify the other 3 lines of my long comment. I'm not familiar with flask, but in other languages exceptions have details as a property of the exception object which you can print to get more details. Also you could show the exact result of print(f"Token received: {token}") and the secret_key. Without any information it's just guessing.

@jps the result of print token is: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJhdWQiOiJsb2NhbGhvc3QiLCJpYXQiOjE3MzA4MDE5OTAsImV4cCI6MTczMDgwNTU5MCwiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMjQiLCJyb2xlIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNoYW5qaW5nIn19.9q4IZMuZ1SlsOqdMmoJ8XW1mynLclbRn_FfHMP4110U
its just the access_token.
if i were to decode it the result is
"iss": "localhost",
"aud": "localhost",
"iat": 1730801990,
"exp": 1730805590,
"data": {
"user_id": "24",
"role": "Admin",
"username": "bob"
